# string to integer type conversion if the string is taken from text box in visual c++ using visual studion n windows forms

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

i need the code to convert the string type data into integer type data if i have entered a numerical value in the text box.
i am using visual c++ windows forms and the visual studio

Comment: @suman: Please put the code you already have into your question, and clearly say whether you're using Managed C++ or C++/CLI (i.e., Visual Studio 7.0/7.1 or 8.0/9.0/10.0).

Answer (score 8):

I think what he wanted was:

```
String^ numberS = "42";
int number;

number = Convert::ToInt32(numberS);
```

Answer (score 7):

> i am using visual c++ windows forms and the visual studio

If it's really Windows Forms (i.e. C++/CLI) it's just `Int32::Parse` or `Int32::TryParse`, just like in any other .NET language.

Comment: `int i = Int32::Parse(myTextBox->Text);` If it still doesn't work, post what *you* already have and describe exactly *what* doesn't work. I don't really know C++/CLI, however, let alone Managed C++.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the variable in a `std::string` instance, you can use streams to do it like this:

```
std::string str = "1";
std::istringstream iss;
iss.str(str);

int val = 0;
iss>>val;
```

Comment: System::String^ txt1 = this->textBox1->Text;
System::String^ s = txt1;
             txt1 = "";
             this->textBox1->Text = txt1;
my code is as above....i have to convert this string s to integer type

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can access the raw character data in the text box you can simply use [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: System::String^ txt1 = this->textBox1->Text; System::String^ s = txt1; txt1 = ""; this->textBox1->Text = txt1; my code is as above....i have to convert this string s to integer type